# Absolute path of current Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In GNU Make, given a makefile in some absolute path `/path/Makefile`, if `Makefile` is the current makefile being processed, how can I recover the absolute path of `Makefile` (e.g., `/path`) regardless of whether such Makefile is being processed and/or included?

The most similar makefile variable I have found is `CURDIR`, but this is like the PWD of the current makefile invocation as far as I understand.

Comment: [`$(realpath $(Makefile))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-file-name_002c-realpath-of)?  (Or `abspath` -- they're subtly different.)

Comment: @G.M., the `Makefile` may have a different name, such as `GNUmakefile` or even `build.mk`. As far as I understand, the solution should support both invocation methods, via `-f` (such as `make -f path/to/Makefile`) and `-C` (such as `make -C path/to/`).

Comment: @Bass yes, and also `includes`. The filename is exactly `Makefile`, and it's for me to write the word `Makefile` explicitely within the file itself (it's local information after all), but what I would like to get is the absolute path of "myself", regardless of execution context.

Comment: @Bass Sorry, `Makefile` was supposed to be the name of a variable containing the filename of interest -- it was an *appalling* choice :-)  Something like `$(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))` might be closer to what's required.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, that was exactly my point, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653359/absolute-path-of-current-makefile#comment136899719_77653359) by [G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m), I would suggest that you combine [`$(firstword)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-firstword) or `$(lastword)` with either [`$(abspath)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-abspath-1) or `$(realpath)`, e.g.:

```
all:
        @echo "$(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))"
        @echo "$(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))"
```

Comment: So according to the docs of `MAKEFILE_LIST`, that means that the lastword in `MAKEFILE_LIST` is "guaranteed" to be "myself" as far as I read the variable BEFORE including any other file, right?

Comment: Yes, and as such you really don't want to do this inside a recipe like that.  Instead, at the beginning of your makefile you should assign a variable (using `:=`!!) to this value.